# Simple Scan not detecting my scanner (Brother DCP-7040)

Tags: 18.04, usb, scanner, brother

I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit. But now Simple Scan does not recognize the scanner.

`sane-find-scanner` outputs:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9, product=0x01e9) at libusb:005:003
  Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage
```

`scanimage -L` outputs:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate).
```

`brscan-skey -l` outputs:

```
  DCP-7040   : brother3:bus1;dev1  : USB               Not registered
```

`dpkg -l | grep -i Brother` outputs:

```
ii  brdcp7040lpr:i386         2.0.2-1      i386         Brother DCP-7040 LPR driver
ii  brscan-skey               0.3.1-1      amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan3:i386              0.2.13-1     i386         Brother Scanner Driver
ii  cupswrapperdcp7040:i386   2.0.2-1      i386         Brother DCP7040 CUPS wrapper driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser    4-1          amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch     1.4.2-3      amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

I have made all the recommendations that I have been able to know:

- "change security in `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules`"
- add user to lp group; add the line "`ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"`' to the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules`
- reinstall DCP7040 Drivers;  reboot every time.

But nothing worked.

In Windows 10 the scanner works. So there is not a hardware problem. Any idea?

---

I reinstall all Brother drivers and made these changes:

`/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules` (at the beginning):

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"`  
ACTION!="add", GOTO="libsane_rules_end"
```

`/lib/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules`:

```
MODE="0666"
```

`/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0777"
```

And I ran this command to change permissions:

```bsh
lsusb | grep -i brother | sed 's/://' | awk '{printf "/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s", $2,$4}' | xargs -i -t sudo chmod 666 "{}"
```

And the problem persists.

`scanimage -L` reports:

```
No scanners were identified...
```

`dpkg -l | grep -i Brother` outputs:

```
ii  brdcp7040lpr:i386     2.0.2-1                                          i386         Brother DCP-7040 LPR driver  
ii  brscan-skey           0.3.1-1                                          amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool  
ii  brscan3               0.2.13-1                                         amd64        Brother Scanner Driver  
ii  cupswrapperdcp7040:i386   2.0.2-1                                      i386         Brother DCP7040 CUPS wrapper driver
```

I observe than these lines disappeared:

```
ii  printer-driver-brlaser    4-1          amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers  
ii  printer-driver-ptouch     1.4.2-3      amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

The point is that when I upgraded to 18.04 LTS first time, I had a similar problem but I do not remember what I did to solve the problem (memory of the elderly).

In summary, I am lost about this problem and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: It's unclear why you have 32-bit i386 scanner driver package.  Brother's support page for this model has a 64-bit scanner driver .deb package.  Have you tried to install it?  Maybe you errantly installed the 32-bit package?

Comment: Thanks @Nmath. I installed all drivers with the tool installation of provider!. Then the instalation didn't workdidn't work in any way! Always scanimage report: "No scanners were identifiedW. Then I installed CUPS driver for 32 bits with hope something work (the other drivers of providers are COMUN for 32 an for 64 bits) but again NO way.

Answer (score 1):

I entered these commands:

```bsh
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/sane
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother3.so /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother3.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother3.so.1 /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother3.so.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother3.so.1.0.7 /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother3.so.1.0.7
```

And it works!!!

`scanimage -L` reports:

```
device `brother3:bus1;dev1' is a Brother DCP-7040 USB scanner
```

And the simple scanner works properly!

This link (#5) saved me: https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/drivers/el-escaner-brother-no-funciona-en-ubuntu-16.04-aunque-el-controlador-esta-instalado/961015336/

In this moment I don't know if all changes were necessary.